# Linux sed - remove at start and at end without delete the middle syntax

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to make a automate script.

I am stuck at the place where I take source code line like:

```
<div class="u-flL condText  "  id="vi-itm-cond" itemprop="itemCondition">
  Seller refurbished
</div>
```

I want the script to always remove the text before and after "Seller Refurbished". I know that "Seller refubished" is a variable that can change.

After `sed` I want this result:

```
'Title: Seller refurbished`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '!/</ {print "Title:"$0}' x.txt
```

Comment: can you explain why it is working? like what the mean of "!/</" because I wanted first to make the command by awk, but then i understood it better with sed.

Comment: This is simply just ignoring the lines with "<" which is the start of a tag. Then processing what is left and prefixing with "Title:"

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/<div[^>]*>/Title: /;s/<\/div>//'
```

Explained:

This one-liner contains two replacement instructions. The first replaces the opening `<div>` tag with `Title:`, and the second removes the closing `</div>` tag.

You may need a few more characters if you want the single quotes around the result, as Bash does not escape anything between single quotes:

```
sed 's/<div[^>]*>/'\''Title: /;s/<\/div>/'\''/'
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks you for helping with explantion :D Just wanting to know if you can show me place to learn sed better because im fking cant understand all /\'[^] marks on the command...(except the default of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
var='<div class="u-flL condText  "  id="vi-itm-cond" itemprop="itemCondition">Seller refurbished</div>'
```

Another `sed` try :

```
sed -E "/Seller refurbished/s/^/'Title: /;s/<[^>]*>//g;s/$/'/" <<<"$var"
'Title: Seller refurbished'
```

Answer (score 0):

With your example this sed is enough

```
sed "/</d;s/.*/'Title: &'/" infile
```